# Use the archivegen tool in Qt Installer Framework to package the files as a 7zip archive

Tags: c++, qt, qt-installer

I want to create a installer in Qt but I make problem.
this is how to Use the archivegen tool to package the files as a 7zip archive and copy it to the data directory.
I search but not find information about use archivegen tool in Qt Installer Framework
How to Use the archivegen tool to package the files as a 7zip archive in Qt Installer Framework and copy it to the data directory.
 url: http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qtifw-1.2/ifw-component-description.html#component-dependencies
please help me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hope you got your answer by now, but just for reference:

If you write "archivegen" on the command line, it replies with:

Usage: archivegen directory.7z directories

Generally, I create a folder inside the data directory that holds whatever I want the installer to unpack, then I use archivegen on the folder. This structure might not be strictly necessary, but it also helps when your user unpacks the contents; they get a folder that holds it and it is not just with unrelated files in the @TargetDir@